# Openvpn forward all traffic not working unless I flush iptables

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, firewall, openvpn

I want to run an openvpn which forwards all traffic, but it only works when I flush my iptables rules. Can someone tell me which rule(s) are causing the problem?

iptables-save output:

````
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [427:27856]
:INPUT ACCEPT [31:1538]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [94:8116]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [94:8116]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:POST_public - [0:0]
:POST_public_allow - [0:0]
:POST_public_deny - [0:0]
:POST_public_log - [0:0]
:POST_public_post - [0:0]
:POST_public_pre - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PRE_public - [0:0]
:PRE_public_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_public_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_public_log - [0:0]
:PRE_public_post - [0:0]
:PRE_public_pre - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_direct
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_ZONES
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING_ZONES -g POST_public
-A POST_public -j POST_public_pre
-A POST_public -j POST_public_log
-A POST_public -j POST_public_deny
-A POST_public -j POST_public_allow
-A POST_public -j POST_public_post
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -g PRE_public
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_pre
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_log
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_deny
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_allow
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_post
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Sep 17 16:58:29 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun Sep 17 16:58:29 2023
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [541673:183161568]
:INPUT ACCEPT [528514:182265252]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [12987:884940]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [553518:419719048]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [553630:419726740]
:FORWARD_direct - [0:0]
:INPUT_direct - [0:0]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PRE_public - [0:0]
:PRE_public_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_public_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_public_log - [0:0]
:PRE_public_post - [0:0]
:PRE_public_pre - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_direct
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -g PRE_public
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_pre
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_log
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_deny
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_allow
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_post
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Sep 17 16:58:29 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun Sep 17 16:58:29 2023
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [541673:183161568]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [553518:419719048]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PRE_public - [0:0]
:PRE_public_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_public_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_public_log - [0:0]
:PRE_public_post - [0:0]
:PRE_public_pre - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -g PRE_public
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_pre
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_log
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_deny
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_allow
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_post
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Sep 17 16:58:29 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun Sep 17 16:58:29 2023
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [523538:179894961]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [112:7692]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [553518:419719048]
:FORWARD_direct - [0:0]
:INPUT_direct - [0:0]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Sep 17 16:58:29 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun Sep 17 16:58:29 2023
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [603:226902]
:FORWARD_IN_ZONES - [0:0]
:FORWARD_OUT_ZONES - [0:0]
:FORWARD_direct - [0:0]
:FWDI_public - [0:0]
:FWDI_public_allow - [0:0]
:FWDI_public_deny - [0:0]
:FWDI_public_log - [0:0]
:FWDI_public_post - [0:0]
:FWDI_public_pre - [0:0]
:FWDO_public - [0:0]
:FWDO_public_allow - [0:0]
:FWDO_public_deny - [0:0]
:FWDO_public_log - [0:0]
:FWDO_public_post - [0:0]
:FWDO_public_pre - [0:0]
:INPUT_ZONES - [0:0]
:INPUT_direct - [0:0]
:IN_public - [0:0]
:IN_public_allow - [0:0]
:IN_public_deny - [0:0]
:IN_public_log - [0:0]
:IN_public_post - [0:0]
:IN_public_pre - [0:0]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_IN_ZONES
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_OUT_ZONES
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -o enp0s3 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -g FWDI_public
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -g FWDO_public
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_pre
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_log
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_deny
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_allow
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_post
-A FWDI_public -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_pre
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_log
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_deny
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_allow
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_post
-A INPUT_ZONES -g IN_public
-A IN_public -j IN_public_pre
-A IN_public -j IN_public_log
-A IN_public -j IN_public_deny
-A IN_public -j IN_public_allow
-A IN_public -j IN_public_post
-A IN_public -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5000 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Sep 17 16:58:29 2023```
````